# Behavior on AngularJS deferred object

Tags: ajax, angularjs, deferred, angular-promise

I was writing a function that will be executed asynchronously. Suddenly a question popped up in my mind.

Let's say I have the following function for updating student records.

```
module.factory('StudentService', function($http, $q) {
    var service = {};

    service.updateStudent = function(studentData) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.put('http://www.example.com/student/update', studentData, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function(response) {
            if (response.success) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            } else {
                // I am not resolving the deferred object here
            }
        }).error(function(response) {
            // I am not rejecting the deferred object here
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return service;
});
```

I want to ask,

1. What will happen to the deferred object if it is not resolved or rejected?
2. If a deferred object is not resolved or rejected, will it result in error for chains like `StudentService.updateStudent(data).then(...)`?
3. Is there any practical usage of neither resolving nor rejecting a deferred object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If deferred is not resolved or rejected, the respective handlers will never be called.
2. No error - just will not call successive handlers in the chain.
3. Too broad for SO

**Off-topic:**

You don't need to use `$q.defer` when you use functions that already return a promise (like `$http`) - this is called a [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). Simply `return` the original promise (or the promise created with `.then`).

Comment: The off-topic note is really useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any practical usage of neither resolving nor rejecting a deferred object?

Yes, ensuring that any callbacks of a chained `.then()` or `.catch()` are never called.

Thus, there are three possible outcomes :

- promise becomes "resolved": promise chain follows the success path.
- promise becomes "rejected": promise chain follows the fail path.
- promise remains "pending": nothing downstream happens, but still could if (references to) the promise still exist and it becomes either resolved or rejected.

That said, it's bad practice to leave a promise hanging. You should endeavour always to resolve or reject.

Off topic but related ...

Like any js object, a promise will be garbage collected when there are *no* references to it. However, due to the nature of promises, it is often very difficult to delete all references - they are not always lexically represented (in the application code). For example, "hidden" reference(s) to promise(s) lurk in every promise chain even where no explicit assignment is made. Every promise, whether it is lexically represented or not, will occupy memory.

Back on topic ...

A promise that will never settle, should either :

- not be created (not always possible)
- be deleted (seldom simple)

Personally, I feel that a lot more work needs to be done in this area.